# Strange behaviour in JavaScript for loops

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code which blocks the event loop and waits of N milliseconds:

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime()
    console.log(`start: ${start}`)
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        const delta = new Date().getTime() - start
        console.log(`milliseconds passed: ${delta}`)
        if (delta > milliseconds) {
            console.log('exiting')
            console.log(`final delta: ${delta}`)
            break
        }
    }
}

sleep(5000)
console.log('the end')
```

When I run it (in browser or Node) I get the expected result:
'start' output, bunch of 'milliseconds passed', and then N milliseconds later I get 'exiting' and 'the end'. No problem here.

But when I comment out `` console.log(`milliseconds passed: ${delta}`) `` in the body of the for loop:

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const start = new Date().getTime()
    console.log(`start: ${start}`)
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        const delta = new Date().getTime() - start
        // console.log(`milliseconds passed: ${delta}`)
        if (delta > milliseconds) {
            console.log('exiting')
            console.log(`final delta: ${delta}`)
            break
        }
    }
}

sleep(5000)
console.log('the end')
```

I get totally surprising results:
I see 'start' output as before, but then it returns immediately and outputs 'the end'. So it's like for loop didn't run at all or stopped running for some reason and program never went into if statement that prints 'exiting'. The only thing that changed between the two snippets of code is commented out console.log statement, and yet behaviour changed drastically.

Can anyone please explain what is going on here?

Comment: because it takes less than 5 sec to count to 10 mil.

Comment: Try replacing the `for` with a `while(true)`. Also, why do you want to block the event loop?

Comment: It's because `console.log` need time to process and block the event loop

Comment: Thank you for help gog, ascpixi! Didn't think of it.

Comment: @ascpixi I used this function to test in which order 2 setTimeouts will schedule tasks if one was declared first but with e.g. 2000 timeout and one declared second with 1000 timeout. If event loop is release right away, then it's clear that second timeout will fire first. But I was interested what will happen if loop is blocked for e.g. 5 seconds, which callback will be scheduled first: the one which had lower timeout value, or the one which was declared first. Turns out it's the one with lower timeout value, regardless order in which in was declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop ran, it just ran quickly, since the bulk of the time-consuming work it does is the `console.log` that you're commenting-out. It doesn't take a modern JavaScript engine long **at all** to loop a million times, even if it is creating an object on each iteration (the `Date`). You can tell if you look for side-effects, like the final value of `i` (since you're using `var`, we can see that value when the loop is over):

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const start = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(`start: ${start}`);
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        const delta = new Date().getTime() - start;
        // console.log(`milliseconds passed: ${delta}`)
        if (delta > milliseconds) {
            console.log("exiting");
            console.log(`final delta: ${delta}`);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i === 1e7) {
        console.log(`Reached main termination condition after ${Date.now() - start}ms`);
    }
    return i;
}

const result = sleep(5000);
console.log(`The end, result = ${result}`);
```

On my machine, that loop completes because `i` reaches `1e7` in just under a second — well before the five seconds are up.

A couple of things worth noting:

- It's best practice **not** to have busy-loops like this in real code. :-)
- `new Date().getTime()` can be replaced with `Date.now()`, which gives you the same thing without an object allocation. All modern and even many obsolete browsers (such as IE9+) support it.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! It's clear now.